# vb.net: how do I add a vb.net form as an attachment to an existing program?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a VB.Net program that I publish as a stand alone program. I'd like to add reports to the program. Ideally, I'd like the reports to be VB.Net forms that my main program can call and open as if they were part of the main program. So I don't know how to create the forms so they can be opened by the main program and I don't know how to call the added forms from the main program.

I do not want to have to publish the add on forms as if they were their own programs. Ideally, I'd like them to look and act as if they were part of the main program and they can only run inside the main program.

I am imagining creating the forms and saving them as DLLs or something similar that the program can read in from a specific directory and then open as sub forms of the main program. Also I'd like the add on forms to be saved as a single file.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like it would work. What do you need help with?

Comment: There are two standard ways to create reports, Crystal reports (client side run, looks like what you need) and SSRS (reporting services, server side, used it a lot). There is no need to reinvent the wheel, even though you may be tempted to do so. If you like reinventing the wheel, first consider using 3rd party solutions of others, who also like reinventing the wheel. [Such as Devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code that ended up working:

```
Private Sub open_report2()

        Dim oType As System.Type
        Dim oAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly
        Dim oObject As System.Object
        oAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\VB.NET\report3\report3\bin\Debug\report3.exe")
        oType = oAssembly.GetType("report3.r1")
        oObject = Activator.CreateInstance(oType)
        oObject.show()
End Sub
```

The open_report2 Sub is in my Main program.

In my report program, report3 is my root namespace and r1 is the class name of the form want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an application called MyReports and build all the forms in that application. Then PUBLISH the MyReports application.

Then in the "main program" you reference the DLL called `MyReports.DLL`.

If you are looking to create a new form based on the report that would be inheritance... so when you Add your new form `ADD` --> `New Item` --> Select `Windows Forms` on the Left and `Inherited Form`. You will hit `BROWSE` and select the form you want to use from MyReports. I have never personally done it but it should create a form based on your form.

If you want to simply display the report within the new app, thats instantiation....

```
Dim myCoolReport as new MyReports.CoolCoolReport
myCoolReport.Show
```

(psuedo code)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But how do I reference the DLL if it was not there when I compiled my main program? I know how to add a reference when I'm creating a program, but I basically want to read all the files in a folder or something and open each one up separately.

Comment: It sounds like instantiation is what I need, I just have to figure out the details of opening the dll at run time.